# How to make p:dataTable columns widths automatically adjusted depending on data?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I use just plain `h:dataTable`:

```
<h:dataTable var="office"
        value="#{reportController.data}" width="100%"
        id="titleRpt" styleClass="data" border="1" cellpadding="2"
        columnClasses="none,rightAlign,rightAlign,rightAlign,rightAlign,rightAlign,rightAlign,rightAlign"
        headerClass="tableHeader"
        rowClasses="oddRow,evenRow"
        cellspacing="0" rendered="#{reportController.doDisplay and reportController.reportType eq 'T'}">
```

I get the following output:

[image]

However, once I change h:dataTable to `p:dataTable` (same code except for the p), I get the following:

[image]

How do I get `PrimeFaces` to automatically set the column widths based on the data within (which is dynamic and retrieved from the DB)?  I am using the `smoothness` [theme](http://primefaces.org/themes).

The reason I have to go with the PrimeFaces version and not the plain JSF one is because I need to have data export functionality and `p:dataExporter` requires that it be nested inside a p:dataTable and not an h one.

Comment: What do you prefer (word wrap, word break, no wrap, hidden, ellipses...), when the length of strings in columns is too long that does not fit the horizontal screen? You can have resizable columns, if you need them. By default, the text is hidden, if it goes beyond the column width which is typically a preferred way in many cases with resizable columns.

Comment: I just want it to follow the same routine as `h:dataTable`, IOW to make each column as wide as the longest cell is